# Is this the most efficient way to match against 15,000 URL hostnames in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using window.location.hostname to get hostname. I want to check the hostname against known hostnames from a list like *f-n-b.com, td.com, shopping.abc.business,key.com,google.com* (totally like **15000** hosts. *I have the list*). If there is a hostname match, the function should return true. So I am using lots of ||

```
'https?:\/\/([a-z0-9]+[.])*td.com'
```

I am using the regex 'https?://([a-z0-9]+[.])*td.com' 
The script seems to be slow. Is this the efficient approach?
**Note**: I thought of concatenating the 15000 urls so there is only 1 match; but someone could come up with *f-n-b.com.UnWantedWebSite.fake* which could do a match with the first *f-n-b.com* in the above list. Right(??).
Looking for plain javascript. I cannot use jQuery or other libs.

Comment: Not sure to understand... You have the list of hostnames, why the regex here? Can't you just lookup your list to see if the value is in there?

Comment: you can use `includes()` method instead of using regular expressions. Isn't it?

Comment: Are the 15,000 names in a database or array or object?

Comment: @Kaiido I have hostnames but window.location.hostname could give me lot of subdomains like credit.shooper.vending.abc.business when I have only abc.business in my list.

Comment: @Gerard They are hardcoded. So I am open to any format, I am flexible for mvp. Definitely not in database.

Comment: Then just `hostnames.find( allowed_host => current_host.endsWith( allowed_host ) );` should still perform better than 15000 regexes.

Comment: @Mandy8055 Let me try http://scratch99.com/web-development/javascript/how-to-get-the-domain-from-a-url/ and convert my URL into array and see if includes() method works.

Comment: @Kaiido almost. with your snippet, `example.com` would correctly match `my.example.com` but it would also match `not-my-example.com`. prefix both `current_host` and `allowed_host` with a dot.

Comment: builds a regex `|` of domain levels greater than 1 (tld) from hostname: `new RegExp(window.location.hostname.split('.').flatMap((x,i,t)=>i < t.length-1 ? t.slice(-i).join('.').toLowerCase()+'$' : []).join('|'),'m').test(hostlistonnewlines)`,  should be adjusted for co.uk and family, but basic gist of it.  If you need further performance you can pre-generate index positions for certain characters and read the hosts in chunks (pre-sorted hosts list)

Comment: @user120242 I tried for websites like given below. IF there is not subdomain, I think it fails. Input=> output.  http(s)://ford.com => ford.com
http(s)://www.ford.com => ford.com
http(s)://2ww-ww43.ford.com => ford.com
http(s)://ford.com/df/df/dg/dg => ford.com
http(s)://www.ford.com/c?se. => ford.com
http(s)://2ww-ww43.ford.com/ => ford.com

Comment: location.hostname doesn't include the protocol.  "ford.com".split('.').flatMap((x,i,t)=>i < t.length-1 ? t.slice(-i).join('.').toLowerCase()+'$' : []).join('|') becomes "ford.com$" which will work because it checks for anything in the list that ends with ford.com.  If you don't want that, add ^ in front t.slice(-i) to full line match

Comment: @user120242 If the website is https://something.com then I am not getting any alert for the script below var inUurl = window.location.hostname;
alert(  inUurl);       I think that is I am not getting the right anwer in such portals. In other portals that has a subdomain, even www. it works okay. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: if youre actually using something.com to test, that domain doesn't exist so in chrome for example you are actually getting chrome's internal url chromewebdata://.  also since you only need to match base domain, you may not need the flatMap regex string building.  that was in case you wanted to do full line matching, so sub1.sub2.sub3.domain.com would match ^sub1.sub2.sub3.domain.com|^sub2.sub3.domain.com$|^sub3.domain.com$|^domain.com$ and so on, which is actually only meaningful if you add a caret

Comment: in the case you only need domain matching, you want: (\.|^)domain.com$ , in the case yo uwant the flatmap string, you should add a caret at the front of "^"+t.slice(-i)

Comment: @user120242 The "something" in https://something.com is actually a placeholder for a real website like becu.org hopecu.org. The regex  does not work on those sites without any subdomain.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRWHz.png works for me

Comment: @user120242 I want to match only domain names. ford.com, becu.org, f-n-b.com whether they have www. or not. The url could have any number of subdomains but i want to match only against base domains ford.com becu.org or f-n-b.com. I am a JS nube.

Comment: right, so if your current URL is www.becu.org or sub1.sub2.becu.org, and your list contains becu.org, it will return true.  if becu.org or sub2.becu.org, etc.. is not in the list, it will return false

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216256/discussion-between-flat-screen-and-user120242).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uses document.domain suffix security restriction to find domain on current page.
If you only need to look for domain in your hostlist:

```js
var domain = (()=>{
  let d = location.hostname.split('.'), dd = document.domain
  let i = 0
  try {
    while(document.domain = d.slice(++i).join('.'));
  } catch (e) {}
  try{
  document.domain = dd // restore document.domain
  } catch(e){}
  return !i ? document.domain : d.slice(i-1).join('.')
})().toLowerCase()
console.log(hostlist.includes(domain+'\n') || hostlist.endsWith('\n'+domain))
```

If you need to match on subdomains but not match on root domains (such that google.com will be false, but www.google.com will be true, if www.google.com is in the hostlist but not google.com):

```
var domains = (()=>{
  let d = location.hostname.split('.'), dd = document.domain,
      res = [location.hostname]
  let i = 0
  try {
    while(document.domain = d.slice(++i).join('.'))
      res.push(document.domain)
  } catch (e) {}
  try{
    document.domain = dd // restore document.domain
  } catch (e) {}
  return res
})()
var re = new RegExp(domains
   .map(d =>'^' + d.replace(/\./g,'\\.').toLowerCase() + '$')
   .join('|'), 'm')
console.log(re, re.test(hostlist))
```

eg:  sub1.sub2.sub3.domain.com will generate RegExp:
     `^sub1\.sub2\.sub3\.domain\.com$|^domain\.com$|^sub3\.domain\.com$|^sub2\.sub3\.domain\.com$`
[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qQ0rl9/1)

Comment: The code works perfectly well. It is not working, for example, shopping.bbc.co.il the xx.yy type TLDs,  but I think the problem is on my end with limited JS knowledge.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what's going on with me.  Really slipping bad here.  It's fixed for sure now.  I've adjusted both.  My domain checking code was doing something silly.

Comment: For reference this domain detection won't work for arbitrary URL strings, only for the current page your browser is on.  For extracting domain from arbitrary URLs you will need to use a domain suffix DB (there's prebuilt js files out there) to get the domain.  This is a shorter hack that tests document.domain security to verify the domain using the browser's built-in domain detecting code.